# Функция mktime() выводит неправильный ответ

Tags: c

Необходимо высчитать количество секунд между двумя моментами времени. Эти момент хранятся в виде структуры tm. Кол-во секунд прошедшее от начала эпохи получаю с помощью mktime(). Проблема в том, что программа считает, что в любом месяце 31 день, как это исправить?

Comment: Покажите ваш код.

Comment: *программа считает, что в любом месяце 31" - автора этой программы - в студию! Народ желает познакомиться. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Смотрим man:

```
ИМЯ
       difftime - вычисляет разницу во времени

ОБЗОР
       #include <time.h>

       double difftime(time_t time1, time_t time0);

ОПИСАНИЕ
       Функция  difftime()  возвращает  количество  секунд, прошедших со времени time1 и до времени time0,
       представленного типом double. Оба времени должны быть  календарным  временем,  т.  е.  временем  (в
       секундах),  прошедшем  с  начала  эпохи (с 00:00:00 1 января 1970 года всеобщего скоординированного
       времени (UTC)).
```